# Angular 4.3 HttpClient making GET and not POST

Tags: angular, rest, rxjs

can please someone explain me, why following code :

```
let body:string = 'username=X&password=Y';
let headers:HttpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({
  'Content-Type': 'application/X-www-form-urlencoded',
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(environment.api_username + ':' + environment.api_password)
});

this.http.post(environment.base_path + '/login/authenticate', body,
  {
    headers: headers
  }
)
```

**make GET request and not POST ?**

Thank you very much

---

Request is made from my localhost to API server (GRAILS 3), CORS is enabled (preflight OPTIONS returns 200), request is to SPRING SECURITY auth login

Comment: How do you know that this is making a get request? Have you checked the network tab in developer tools(F12) ?

Comment: Hi, yes exactly ... should i post screenshot ?

Comment: That would be really good

Comment: been 5 mins waiting for your image. wanna experience it.

Comment: So when i have removed 'body' from post call  (.post(url, {...headers...}) - POST request has been made. How can i put Form Data into POST ?

Comment: @k11k2 : Sorry ... been experimenting .... i guess screen is not needed anymore

Comment: Form data should be part of the body?

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. So post call works, problem was that i have typo ''X-www' ... should be 'x-www'. After fixing 'x' - POST is executed. But before POST, there is one GET request executed - why is this happening, that is still mystery to me :-)